# Чем заменить java-интерфейс в с++? Нужно вызвать функцию с заданным прототипом

Tags: java, c++

В общем есть класc `LCgenerator`, который с помощью метода `next()` генерирует псевдослучайные числа. Так же есть класс `Sample`, который должен хранить значения. Я хочу создать конструктор класса `Sample`, который `n` раз вызывал бы `next()`, тем самым заполняя выборку.

Джава-программисты делают так:

```
interface Generator
{
    next();
}

class LCgenerator implemets Generator
{
    // определяю next();
}

class Sample
{
    public Sample(Generator g, int n)
    {
        // вызывать n раз функцию next() из экземпляра g класса,
        // реализующего интерфейс Generator
    }
}

Sample s = new Sample( new LCGenerator(param), n);
```

Как такая проблема решается в c++? Интерфейсов в языке нет. Делать абстрактный класс? Мне кажется это как-то некрасиво, что-ли. Использовать указатели на функцию? Ну тогда непонятно, как передать в такую функцию метод конкретного экземпляра.

```
template<class T>
class Sample
{
    //...
    Sample( T(*get)(), int n );
    //...
};

int main()
{
    Sample<double> LC1( LCgenerator(1,7,3,32).next, 10000 ); //не компилит
}
```

Может быть как-то использовать указатель на метод?
В общем, c++ программисты, какое(-ие) решение(-я) этой заморочки у вас считается(-ются) красивым(-и)?

Comment: А вы не в курсе, что класс все методы которого виртуальные и есть интерфейс?

Comment: @ArchDemon, не был в курсе, но по-сути, да. Т.е. c++ программисты абстрактные классы делают в таких ситуациях?

Comment: почему бы и нет, тем более множественное наследование есть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java-style:

```
class Generator{
public:
    virtual int next() = 0;
    virtual ~Generator(){} //Это важно!
};

class LCgenerator : public Generator{
    int next(){
        return 42;
    }
};

void foo(Generator *generator){
    //Пользуемся генератором
    int i = generator->next();
}
```

stl-style:

```
class LCgenerator{
public:
    int operator()(){
        return 42;
    }
};

template<class Generator>
void foo(Generator generator){
    //Пользуемся генератором
    int i = generator();
}
```

Не совсем stl-style, но очень похоже:

```
class LCgenerator{
public:
    int next(){
        return 42;
    }
};

template<class Generator>
void foo(Generator generator){
    //Пользуемся генератором
    int i = generator.next();
}
```

Первый способ один в один как в вашем примере на java. Используется позднее связывание со всеми вытекающими накладными расходами на этапе выполнения. Второй и третий способ увеличивают время компиляции, но зато на этапе выполнения не происходит ничего лишнего.

Так же стоит добавить, что второй способ позволяет использовать не только объекты классов у которых определен `operator()`. В качестве генератора можно так же передавать указатели на функции и лямбды.